# More than one SKSpriteNode?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

This is how I am currently doing it.

```
    patch1.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 80, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 205)
    patch1.yScale = 0.75
    patch1.xScale = 0.75
    self.addChild(patch1)

    percent1.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 80, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 125)
    percent1.xScale = 0.5
    percent1.yScale = 0.5
    self.addChild(percent1)

    patch2.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 80, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 55)
    patch2.yScale = 0.75
    patch2.xScale = 0.75
    self.addChild(patch2)

    percent2.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - 80, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 25)
    percent2.xScale = 0.5
    percent2.yScale = 0.5
    self.addChild(percent2)
```

except I have 8 of each of them. I just figured that after all is said and done it will be a pain to update these all frequently. Is there a better way to have these set up so it will be easier/more efficient to update them? Eventually I am going to add a function that when tapped percent++

Edit: Here is the image[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what these sprite nodes are doing in your app, but assuming they all are doing similar things, you can create a subclass of SKNode and declare these in that subclass.

```
class MySubclass: SKNode {
    // Declare variables here.... initialize them in init().... ect.
    let node1 = SKSpriteNode()
    let node2 = SKSpriteNode()

    override init(){
        // DON'T FORGET TO ADD YOUR NODES AS CHILDREN!!
        self.addChild(node1)
        self.addChild(node2)
    }
}
```

Then in your main view you can do something like this:

```
let myNodeSubClass = MySubclass() //Assuming your subclass init doesn't have any parameters

override init(size: CGSize){
    super.init(size)
    myNodesubClass.position = CGPointMake(200, 200) //This will set the position of all the children of your sub class
}
```

Comment: I should have added more details. What each is is a score and node. The node will be tapped and it will increase the score. The patches all have a preset place. I updated the original to show what my view looks like. @Aaron

Answer (score 0):

You could use method.

```
func createSomething(yPosition: CGFloat,xScale: CGFloat, yScale: CGFloat) {

    let percent = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Something")
    percent.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2 - 80, self.frame.size.height / 2 + yPosition )
    percent.xScale = xScale
    percent.yScale = yScale
    self.addChild(percent)
}
```

And you add objects like this:

```
   self.createSomething(205, xScale: 0.75, yScale: 0.75);

   self.createSomething(125, xScale: 0.5, yScale: 0.5);

   self.createSomething(55, xScale: 0.75, yScale: 0.75);

   self.createSomething(-25, xScale: 0.5, yScale: 0.5);
```